# Creating a 3D model of object with non-overlapping stereo cameras?

Tags: computer-vision, computer-science, vision, 3d-reconstruction

Say I wanted to create a 3D model of an object, and I have a pair of cameras that will take a photo of the object at a given distance (the position of the cameras is fixed relative to the object itself.) However, the Field Of View of the cameras is such that not all of the object is visible for each camera; only part of the object is visible for both cameras. See the figure below for what I mean.

[image: Figure of non-overlapping cameras]

Is it possible to create a 3D model of the object using the images from the two cameras, even thought they do not completely see the entirety of the model? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: You can always create "a" 3D model. But how accurate this is (or if it is even close to reality), depends a lot on what assumptions you can make about the scene (e.g., you may only consider rectangular objects, or be able to recreate parts of the shape from shadows, or ...) --> As is, the question is too broad.

Comment: @chtz Let's say it's like the inside of an antenna and the object won't be able to self-shadow.